# Let $X_t=\int_0^t f(X_s)ds+W_t$ where $f$ is continuous. Why $X\in W^{1,2}$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $W^{1,2}=\{X\in L^2([0,T]\times \Omega ), X'\in L^2([0,T]\times \Omega ) \}$.

Let $$X_t=\int_0^t f(X_s)ds+W_t,$$
where $f$ is Lipschitz continuous with linear growth and $W$ is a Brownian motion. We set $Z_t=X_t-W_t$. Then, in my exercise they claim that $X$ and $Z$ are in $W^{1,2}$. So, I agree that $Z\in W^{1,2}$ since $Z_t'=f(X_t)$. But why $X\in W^{1,2}$ ? What is the signification of $X_t'$ ?

Comment: Does $W^{1,2}$ refer to the Sobolev space ? (cf [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space#Multidimensional_case))

Comment: I think so, but why $X$ is derivable ? (in distribution sense...)